# Is it possible to catch scroll event for an Instant Articles page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

Is it possible to catch scroll event for a page when a user sees a particular content piece?

We need to send analytics requests when user see images on Instant Articles page

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo` (more documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/)

I don't think this method allows you to "catch it" per se but there is a way for you to poll it using `setInterval` which should allow you to detect when the position of the page has changed.